# Getting exact modifier key state in NSView flagsChanged

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I am using flagsChanged in NSView to trigger events when a modifier key is pressed or released. However, I do not quite understand how to get the actual new state of the key when this happens, short of checking the state of each modifier key manually. I am currently using my own state array to check it, but this seems wrong and is not reliable. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check the event that gets passed into `flagsChanged:` against the various modifier key masks that you're interested in:

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
   if (([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) == NSAlternateKeyMask) {
       // Do something based on the alt/option key being pressed
    } else if (([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) == NSCommandKeyMask){
       // Do something based on the command key being pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, but how do I know for example if it's the right or left alt that was pressed or released?

Comment: i.e. I hold down left alt, then press right alt up and down, (([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) == NSAlternateKeyMask) will stay true while left alt is held down

Comment: Ok, I found this, which seems to do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715910/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-between-left-and-right-shift-keys-being-pressed

Pretty dumb way of doing things I must say :)

Comment: You don't need the `== NSAlternateKeyMask` part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by checking "manually".  The `flagsChanged:` method gives you an `NSEvent*`, and you can pass that a `modifierFlags` message.