# Distinguishing left and right shift in a custom OS X keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am trying to define a keyboard layout for OS X (Mavericks).
My goal is to distinguish left/right shifts.
I have created this test layout but without luck. Both combinations left/right shift + q produces the same.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE keyboard SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/KeyboardLayout.dtd">
<keyboard group="0" id="5000" name="U.S." maxout="2">
  <layouts>
    <layout first="0" last="0" modifiers="48" mapSet="312" />
  </layouts>
  <modifierMap id="48" defaultIndex="0">
    <keyMapSelect mapIndex="0">
      <modifier keys="" />
    </keyMapSelect>
    <keyMapSelect mapIndex="1">
      <modifier keys="shift" />
    </keyMapSelect>
    <keyMapSelect mapIndex="2">
      <modifier keys="rightShift" />
    </keyMapSelect>
  </modifierMap>
  <keyMapSet id="312">
    <keyMap index="0">
      <key code="12" output="q" />
    </keyMap>
    <keyMap index="1">
      <key code="12" output="1" />
    </keyMap>
    <keyMap index="2">
      <key code="12" output="2" />
    </keyMap>
  </keyMapSet>
</keyboard>
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but, programmatically it is possible. See for example [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715910/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-between-left-and-right-shift-keys-being-pressed).

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed this option. I just wonder if anyone is using keylayout with this distinction since it should be solvabel via keyboard layout but sadly doesn't work...

Comment: I have the same problem. Shift and rightShift are both treated as anyShift it seems? It's possible to do this in Karabiner though: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it is not possible.

You are correct that in theory it should be possible to treat `rightShift`, `rightOption` and `rightControl` separately, but this has never worked.

[The docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2056/_index.html):

> Note that many hardware keyboards do not have both left and right versions of a modifier key. It is usually safest to specify modifers in terms of the "any" variants (anyShift, anyOption, anyControl).

However, the problem is not the hardware. Programatically, right keys can indeed be detected (e.g. using https://manytricks.com/keycodes/), but not in `.keylayout`s. Even if you explicitly remap a key to `right_shift` using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), macOS will still use your `shift` (= left shift) key map.