# Trap each SHIFT key independently on OS X

Tags: macos, hook, keyboard-events, tap, iokit

I have working code ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336086/make-shift3-produce-not-%C2%A3-on-osx-by-code)) that traps keycodes for non-modifier keydown events, and modifier-changed events.

But if you do:

```
LSHIFT down -> RSHIFT down -> RSHIFT up -> LSHIFT up
```

... the inner 2 actions will not trigger either of these hooks, because the modifier state is not changing!

*(EDIT: Woops! I should have tested that out before writing, because actually a new modifier-changed is produced by each actual change.)*

My only thought is maybe to additionally watch at an even lower level ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372852/how-to-tap-hook-f7-through-f12-and-power-eject-on-a-macbook-keyboard)) -- but that doesn't look pretty no matter which angle I look at it from.

Comment: No, they have separate keycodes -- I confirmed this by executing the code in the second link.

Comment: Assuming you are making a Cocoa app with Obj-C (given the OSX tag) you can use the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715910/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-between-left-and-right-shift-keys-being-pressed). Implement `-(void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent*)` and check `[theEvent modifiers]`. LShift is 131330 and RShift is 131332

Comment: @Arc676, you groover!  I've just tested and it does indeed correctly isolate L&R Shift events.  Even composites like +L+R-L-R and +L+R-R-L. If you put it as an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from Justin Boo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715910/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-between-left-and-right-shift-keys-being-pressed)

I've added some more modifier just in case someone stumbles upon this and wants other keys as well.

```
- (void) flagsChanged:(NSEvent*)theEvent{
    if ([theEvent modifier] == 131330){
        //do stuff regarding left shift
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 131332){
        //do stuff regarding right shift
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 65792){
        //caps lock is on
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 8388864){
        //FN key pressed
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 262401){
        //control key pressed
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 524576){
        //option key pressed
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 1048840){
        //command key pressed
    }else if ([theEvent modifier] == 256){
        //there are no modified pressed and caps lock is off
    }
}
```

I recommend storing some `BOOL`s in your class such as `LShiftDown` and `RShiftDown` as this method should be called when the modifiers are pressed. You can probably also detect this property in your `keyDown` implementation to detect differences such as "a" and "A".